# Studio won't print array elements when I test. (Java)

Tags: eclipse, element

I'm working with eclipse and when I want the program to print either all the array elements or just a single array element via indexing. It doesn't return an error or even an address when I run the program.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FavoriteListMaker {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program is to help you order a favorites list. Please enter the amount of items on the list.");
    int ListSize = inputDevice.nextInt();
    String [] TopXA = new String [ListSize + 1];
    int [] TopXB = new int[ListSize + 1];

    for (int x = 0; x < TopXA.length; ++ x)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an item to be organized on the list");
        String item = inputDevice.nextLine();
        TopXA[x] = item;
        System.out.println("You have " + (ListSize - x) + " items left to fill on the list.");
    }

    System.out.println("Now we will compare each item on the list with every item on the list one at a time.");
    System.out.println("We will ask you a series a question on whether you like item A better then item B and tally the score.");
    System.out.println("At the end the item with the most points wins.");

    for (int y = 0; y < TopXA.length; ++ y) 
        for (int z = 0; z < TopXA.length; ++ z)
        {
            String compareA = TopXA[y];
            String compareB = TopXA[z];

            System.out.println("Do you prefer "  + compareA + " or " + compareB + " .");
            System.out.println("If you prefer " + compareA + "Please press 1. If you prefer " + compareB + " please press 2.");
            int choice = inputDevice.nextInt();

            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                TopXB[y] =+ 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                TopXB[z] =+ 2;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("I'm sorry but that is not a valid input.");
            }
        }
```

When I run the code it will print out. "Do you prefer or ." instead of the array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer - I don't have eclipse, I dont program in Java

Please check two things 
1) The for loop for y doesn't have curly brackets
2) Please check array 'TopXA' to see if 'item' is being populated in array once you input it.
3) Are CompareA and CompareB being assigned values?

EDIT - found problem

Add scanner.nextLine(); after the nextINt line.

Comment: As far as I can tell it should be populated but the only way I know how to check is too print the array which leads me back to square one. I've also tried populating the array directly with TopXA[x] = inputDevice.nextLine();


With the same results.

Comment: Just do  System.out.println(TopXA[0]); and see if it prints a value.

Comment: I did that. In fact I did that first before I tried putting it in a variable same results.

Comment: Correct. According to all the sites I've gone to and my Java book it should print something. Or at least complain with an error that array element is null.

Comment: Okay - so 'Item' is not getting value properly - there is some problem in initialization, you need to check the scanner code

Comment: Did you import Java.util?

Comment: Yes I did import Java.util

Comment: Your issue should be solved now. I edited my answer but the person above me gave the correct syntax at  the same time- he referenced the object instance, I referenced the class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `nextInt()` method is not consuming the newline character (see [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)). This leads to the fact that your first element in the list is empty. In the first iteration (y=0, z=0) of the nested for-loops this empty element gets printed two times.

Try adding `inputDevice.nextLine()` after each `nextInt()` call and you will see that it is working ;)

And PLEASE: Don't name variables uppercase!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FavoriteListMaker {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program is to help you order a favorites list. Please enter the amount of items on the list.");
    int listSize = inputDevice.nextInt();
    inputDevice.nextLine();
    String [] topXA = new String [listSize];
    int [] topXB = new int[listSize];

    for (int x = 0; x < topXA.length; ++x)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an item to be organized on the list");
        String item = inputDevice.nextLine();
        topXA[x] = item;
        System.out.println("You have " + (listSize - x) + " items left to fill on the list.");
    }

    System.out.println("Now we will compare each item on the list with every item on the list one at a time.");
    System.out.println("We will ask you a series a question on whether you like item A better then item B and tally the score.");
    System.out.println("At the end the item with the most points wins.");

    for (int y = 0; y < topXA.length; ++y) 
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < topXA.length; ++z)
        {
            String compareA = topXA[y];
            String compareB = topXA[z];

            System.out.println("Do you prefer "  + compareA + " or " + compareB + " .");
            System.out.println("If you prefer " + compareA + "Please press 1. If you prefer " + compareB + " please press 2.");
            int choice = inputDevice.nextInt();
            inputDevice.nextLine();

            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                topXB[y] =+ 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                topXB[z] =+ 2;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("I'm sorry but that is not a valid input.");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yup, I was going through Java syntax to figure that one out.

Comment: There is only 1 nextInt() call. So I add an inputDevice.nextLine() after that one at the beginning?

Comment: There is another in the nested for-loops ;)

Comment: Thanks problem solved.....sorry accident on the variable name I usually do name them lowercase.

Comment: Your welcome. Even if the answer with no explanation is the accepted one :/

Comment: Yes, please do accept infotoni's answer - that's a more elaborate and detailed answer.